# how to deep copy eigen block into a vector?

Tags: eigen

I load an Eigen matrix A(5,12), and I would like to assign a new eigen Vector as the first 7 values of the first row of matrix A.
Somehow, it doesn't work...

Later I realize that block returns a pointer to the original data. How to deep copy the block into Eigen Vector?

```
Eigen::MatrixXd A(5,12);
Eigen::VectorXd B(12); B = A.row(0);
Eigen::VectorXd C(7); C = B.head(7);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! "Somehow, it doesn't work"-problems should provide sufficient code to reproduce the problem and a description of the expected behavior. See how to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Block methods like `block`, `col`, `row`, `head`, etc. return views on the original data, but operator `=` always perform a deep copy, so you can simply write:

```
VectorXd C = A.row(0).head(7);
```

This will perform a single deep copy. With Eigen 3.4 [slicing API](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html), you'll also be able to write:

```
VectorXd C = A(0,seqN(0,7));
```